# Reading hierarchy of a JSON using value

Tags: json, soapui, hl7-fhir, rhapsody

I want to get the hierarchy of a JSON using a value. For example: In below JSON for value "Medical record number" , the desired information is "resource->identifier->type->coding->display" . IS their any inbuilt function to do so. 
The one way to look for opening and ending braces to locate nodes. Any other efficient way ?

```
{
"resourceType": "Bundle",
"type": "transaction",
"entry": [
    {
        "fullUrl": "Patient/996-756-495-101",
        "resource": {
            "resourceType": "Patient",
            "id": "996-756-495-101",
            "identifier": [
                {
                    "type": {
                        "coding": [
                            {
                                "system": "http://hl7.org/fhir/v2/0203",
                                "code": "MR",
                                "display": "Medical record number"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "system": "https://www.lumc.nl",
                    "value": "996-756-495-101"
                }
            ],
            "name": [
                {
                    "use": "usual",
                    "family": [
                        "Levin_4"
                    ],
                    "given": [
                        "Henry_4"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "gender": "male",
            "birthDate": "1932-09-24",
            "maritalStatus": {
                "coding": [
                    {}
                ]
            },
            "managingOrganization": {
                "reference": "Organization/12"
            }
        },
        "request": {
            "method": "POST",
            "url": "Patient",
            "ifNoneExist": "identifier=https://www.lumc.nl|996-756-495-101"
        }
    },
    {
        "fullUrl": "FamilyMemberHistory/d42ebf70-5c89-11db-b0de-0800200c9a66",
        "resource": {
            "resourceType": "FamilyMemberHistory",
            "id": "d42ebf70-5c89-11db-b0de-0800200c9a66",
            "patient": {
                "reference": "Patient/996-756-495-101"
            },
            "status": "Partial",
            "relationship": {
                "coding": [
                    {
                        "system": "http://hl7.org/fhir/ValueSet/v3-FamilyMember",
                        "code": "FTH",
                        "display": "Father"
                    }
                ],
                "text": "Father"
            },
            "gender": "male",
            "bornDate": "1912",
            "deceasedBoolean": true
        },
        "request": {
            "method": "POST",
            "url": "FamilyMemberHistory"
        }
    },
    {
        "fullUrl": "FamilyMemberHistory/a13c6160-5c8b-11db-b0de-0800200c9a66",
        "resource": {
            "resourceType": "FamilyMemberHistory",
            "id": "a13c6160-5c8b-11db-b0de-0800200c9a66",
            "patient": {
                "reference": "Patient/996-756-495-101"
            },
            "status": "Partial",
            "relationship": {
                "coding": [
                    {
                        "system": "http://hl7.org/fhir/ValueSet/v3-FamilyMember",
                        "code": "MTH",
                        "display": "Mother"
                    }
                ],
                "text": "Mother"
            },
            "gender": "female",
            "bornDate": "1912",
            "deceasedBoolean": false
        },
        "request": {
            "method": "POST",
            "url": "FamilyMemberHistory"
        }
    }
]
```

}

Comment: Is that do you want to retrieve the value `Medical record number`?

Comment: No, the value **Medical record number** is known prehand, i want to know inside which element /node it is present ( the whole hierarchy of it).

Comment: Do you expect the answer specific to Rhapsody?. I can give a script how to parse in Javascript & Mirth

Comment: I need to run that in SoapUI which uses grrovy, so Java script should do. Even if not, I can understand the logic behind it and use it.

Comment: Just curious to know your use case, why do you need to have the hierarchy of keys?

Comment: Hi Rao, The overflow goes something like this- an input message (HL7) is converted into JSON and the task is to check whether th mapping from HL7 to JSON has been done properly. The logic I want to use is to search in the JSON the actual value of a HL7 field that has to be mapped to JSON and get the hierarchy. The hierarchy can be then matched with the stored hierarchy to confirm that the mapping has been done to correct resource and element.